# Why coq doesn't use subtyping for logical or?

Tags: coq, type-theory, subtyping

By subtyping, here I mean implicit coercion between types, not `sig`.

In programming languages, sum types have associated data and it matters which variant is being used, so e.g. `A` can not be a subtype of `Either<A,B>` in haskell. The same is true for decideable coq. That is, `A` can not be a subtype of `A + B` in general, since `A + A` has one bit more data than `A`.

However, `Prop`s have no data in runtime, so why coq doesn't consider `A` a subtype of `A \/ B` and allow using each member of it as a member of `A \/ B` without explicit `or_introl`? I think it makes proof shorter and more generic. Is there a fundamental limit or unsoundness problem that makes it impossible, or it is just an unneeded feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue is indeed one of utility:

If you're looking at proving `A\/B`, you probably aren't building a proof of `A` or `B` by hand, but rather applying a bunch of powerful techniques with no regard for efficiency or conciseness, for exactly the reasons you said.

This means you can apply powerful tactics such as `auto` or `intuition`, or even `firstorder` if you're feeling lucky.

These tactics prove much more than `A -> A \/ B`, and often perform many steps, including that one, which makes the coercion somewhat useless (and perhaps even confusing!).

Comment: It's not that useless, for example I have a proof of `a < b`, some lemma needs `a <= b`, and automated tactics are not aware that I want to use that lemma. In this case I should add a step for `a <= b` proof or have a duplicate version of that lemma with `a < b`. But if `a <= b` was notation for `a < b \/ a = b` and `X` was subtype of `X \/ Y`, it would just work. Some wrapper tactic around apply could do this job as well, but I think subtyping here is nice to have.

Comment: That's fair, but in general, depending on the precise definition of `a < b` in relation to `a <= b` is quite finicky; already being to clever about the precise relationship (it's currently `a < b := S a <= b`) can get you in trouble.

Generally you want to build a "domain specific tactic" which knows what it needs to deduce about facts in your environment (in this case generally you'd want to call `lia` at the right moment to discharge all your `a </<= b` obligations).